# Selenium: How to locate dynamic element like notification messages

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am using Selenium with Web Driver.

I have a form to be filled up in a Light Box. Now when I click "submit". That Light Box gets closed and an easy notification gets generated on top of the page which gets disappeared after a couple of sec.

Now my question is: When I do

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='createCaseBtn']")).click(); // x-path of submit button
```

How shall I check whether that notification message appeared on the UI.

Because when I do

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='easyNotification']")).getText(); // x-path of easyNotification message
```

I shows me that it is Unable to locate the element which seems logically correct because at that time the notification message is not present on the UI. It is only after completion of AJAX Request (for submition of form) that message gets appeared on the UI.

Please help!!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have used Explicit Waits. It worked fine for me:

An explicit waits is code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code. The worst case of this is Thread.sleep(), which sets the condition to an exact time period to wait. There are some convenience methods provided that help you write code that will wait only as long as required. WebDriverWait in combination with ExpectedCondition is one way this can be accomplished.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(".//*[@id='easyNotification']")));
```

Answer (score 0):

well. when I deal with AJAX I always use fluent wait approach.
Suppose you have locator of the message appering after click on submit button:

```
String xPathMessage= ".//*[@id='easyNotification']"; 

    public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
            Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                    .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

            WebElement foo = wait.until(
    new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                            return driver.findElement(locator);
                    }
                    }
    );
                               return  foo;              }     ;

//simply call the method:
String text=fluentWait(By.xpath(xPathMessage)).getText();
```

from the documentation on fluent wait:
*An implementation of the Wait interface that may have its timeout and polling interval configured on the fly.
Each FluentWait instance defines the maximum amount of time to wait for a condition, as well as the frequency with which to check the condition. Furthermore, the user may configure the wait to ignore specific types of exceptions whilst waiting, such as NoSuchElementExceptions when searching for an element on the page.*

The described above approach also not bad  in pair with isElementPresent:

```
public bool isElementPresent(By selector)
{
    return driver.FindElements(selector).Any();
}
```

or that:

```
public bool isElementPresent(By selector)
{
    return driver.FindElements(selector).size()>0;
}
```

Hope this works for you